# Задача оптимизации

Tags: python, алгоритм

Как лучше решить гибрид транспортной задачи и комбинаторике в python.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pathx = 'D:\JobD\Test.xlsx'
x11 = pd.ExcelFile(pathx)
obraz = x11.parse('Orders')

ShagpoZ = 30
PrirostX = 100
PrirostY = 100

for x in np.sort(obraz.X.unique()):
    for i in range(100,500,100):
        print(x,i+x)
```

Есть блоки с координатами X,Y,Z и атрибутивными данными. Необходимо чтобы программа набирала блоки по условию Класс, Объем (в идеале и соотношение атрибутивных данных), но учитывала соотношение координат, если берем блок на n-ном горизонте, то берем все что выше по Z отметке и там все блоки со сдвигом по координатам на определенных шаг (к примеру +100м по осям X и Y).

Как понимаю это задача линейного программирования с сдвигом в комбинаторику, можно как-то решить её в python?

[image: Образец таблицы данных]

Comment: Приведите пример входных и выходных данных. У вас есть список объектов и вам нужно получить некоторый подсписок по каким-то условиям?

Comment: Входные данные: Pandas Dataframe: X,Y,Z,Class,Volume. Выходные данные новый атрибут в Pd.Dataframe, показывающий принадлежность блока к набору. К примеру 1 год работы, задаем суммарный объем, а программа выдает варианты если они есть по набору блоков. Ограничение это геометрия- можно брать блоки только соседние и если есть блоки выше то по ним необходим сдвиг по осям координат в размере самих блоков

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/1_EzaKfIC4kfmA Вот приложил массив данных